# Facing an issue with go-openapi/analysis library using glide

Tags: go, openapi, glide-golang

I was trying to install the `go-openapi/analysis` using the `glide`. Using the `glide up -v` command for installing. Glide version v0.13.2 and go version 1.11

## glide.yaml

```
package: abc
import:
- package: github.com/go-openapi/analysis
  version: 0.16.0
```

Got this error during the installation process.

```
Keeping github.com/go-openapi/analysis 0.16.0 [INFO] 
--> Setting version for github.com/mailru/easyjson to 2f5df55504ebc322e4d52d34df6a1f5b503bf26d. 
[ERROR] Error scanning path/filepath: cannot find package "." in: 
.glide/cache/src/https-path-filepath
```

Comment: which version of `go`?

Comment: Using go 1.11 version

Comment: how were you trying to install, I didn't find any problem, my installation was successfull

Comment: Added the glide.yaml file in the question.